# Create an array of points in time not longer than 30 days based on two time inputs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

How something like this could be achieved? Preferrably in Moment.js or vanilla js. I have the following input:

```
   const input = {
        from: "2022-01-01",
        to: "2022-03-05"
    }
```

If number of days is greater than 30 (like in this case it's 64) I need to split it into an array of objects containing start and end dates that define "chunks" of time not greater than 30 days. So based on the example input I expect the following output:

```
const output = [
    {
        from: "2022-01-01", // 30 days
        to: "2022-01-30" 
    },
    {
        from: "2022-01-31", // 30 days
        to: "2022-03-01" 
    },
    {
        from: "2022-03-02", // 4 days
        to: "2022-03-05" 
    },
]
```

Could someone provide some guidance please? Thanks!